# Determining the type of a singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)=\frac{sin 3z - sin z}{sin z(sinz -z)}$

First of all I am not sure that the singularities of this function are only $0$, and $\infty$. Is $0$ the only solution to the equation, $sinz=z$?

Furthermore, I believe that $0$ is a removable singularity since:

$f(z)=\frac{-4 sin^3z}{sin z(sinz -z)}$ which goes to $0$ as $z \rightarrow 0$

I found this last equality using formulas about sine and cosine, and for the limit I used L'Hospital Rule.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this correct? Can you help me with these questions? Thanks for any help.

Comment: $\sin z - z$ has infinitely many zeros because otherwise it would be of the form $P(z) e^{f(z)}$ for some polynomial $P$ and entire function $f$, then $\Re(f(z))\le a+b|z|$ implies $f(z)=cz$ but $P(z)e^{cz}$ is not odd, contradiction. The modulus of the zeros are distributed more or less like those of $\sin z$.

Comment: So, are you saying that $\infty$ is not isolated? What is the theorem for your claim in the first sentence? I do not know that, can you give me some resources so that I can learn more?

Comment: Isolated what of what function ? If $g$ is entire and has finitely zeros then $G(z)=g(z)/P(z)$ is entire with no zeros thus $G'/G$ is entire and so is $\log G$. The non-trivial part is that the upper bound for $\Re(f(z))$ is enough to conclude that $f$ is a polynomial (this is the key to Hadamard's factorization theorem)

Comment: What about my argument for the limit? Is $0$ a removable singularity? @reuns

Comment: No. Find the order of the zero of each term, $\sin z -z$ has a zero of order $3$, $\sin z$ of order $1$, and $\sin 3z-\sin z$ of order $1$ (derivative $=3-1\ne 0$). In the denominator you meant $(\sin z)(\sin (z)-z)$ right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the essential information is already given in the comments by @reuns. This is a supplementary hint showing that $f$ doesn't have a removable singularity at $z=0$.

> Using the *[identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Triple-angle_formulae)* $\sin 3z=3\sin z-4\sin ^3z$ and the series expansion of *[sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions)* we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> f(z)&=\frac{\sin 3z-\sin z}{\sin z(\sin z -z)}\\
> &=\frac{\left(3\sin z-4\sin^3 z\right) -\sin z}{\sin z(\sin z -z)}\\
> &=\frac{2-4\sin ^2 z}{\sin z -   z}\\
> &=\frac{2-4\left(z-\frac{1}{6}z^3+\cdots\right)^2}{\left(z-\frac{1}{6}z^3+\cdots\right)-z}\\
> &=\frac{2-4z^2+\frac{4}{3}z^4-\cdots}{-\frac{1}{6}\color{blue}{z^3}+\cdots}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and observe $z=0$ is a singularity of 3rd order.